# SQL force application to encrypt connection

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ssl, web-config

I've enabled SSL connections to my database and am able to manually encrypt connections to the db from my machine.  I now want my app to encrypt connections to the database but am unsure of what to do?  Is there something I can add to the connection string in my web.config file in order to force a handshake?

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

Edit-
DB - SQL 2014
DB Server - Server O8R2

Comment: What programming language? What kind of database server? etc .... All question we need before being able to help

Comment: i suspect web.config implies .net (if my suspcions are correct add the tag!).

Comment: Updated tags and added more info. Apologies.

Comment: Did you bother trying google? FIrst hit on "sql server encrypt connectioN" goes to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx for me - which has the title "Encrypting Connections to SQL Server"

Answer (score -1):

This is working with me:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" C:\Websites\mywebsite -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "appSettings" C:\Websites\mywebsite -prov "DataProtectionConfigurationProvider"
```

Comment: This example shows how to encrypt sections of the config file so that the connection string is protected.  The OP was asking how the connection itself can be encrypted.